# Splitting an already labelled image for object detection

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, geotiff

I have a large geotiff file of elevation data that I would like to use for object detection. I've labelled the objects (originally as a .shp) and converted the labels into a single geojson.

From reading object detection tutorials it seems that I need to split this large image into multiple images for training/testing. Is there a way to do this using the original labels, so that I don't need to re-label each smaller image?

If anyone has any useful tutorials/end to end examples of preparing satellite data for object detection that would also be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `GeoJSON` file you have should have the co-ordinates to get the bounding box for the named portion of the original image. (If you want to know how to do that, see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313023/120175). Once you have the bounding box, you can use any imaging library ([Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Pillow-SIMD](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd)) to get the sub-image that you have named (with the name in the same geojson object that contained the coordinates you took for getting bounding box). You can operate them while they're in memory or save them (they can be treated as independent images themselves) with these imaging library. These images can be used for training.